# Mean Square Displacement as a Function of Time in Python

Tags: python, random-walk

I have been assigned the following:

> "...Plot your final MSD as a function of δt. Include errorbars σ = std(MSD)/√N,
>   where std(MSD) is the standard deviation among the different runs and N is the
>   number of runs. N.B.: This is the formula for the error of the mean for statistically
>   independent, normally distributed time series.
>   You should find that your curve resembles
>
> MSD(δt) = Dδt,
>
> i. e., it is linear as a function of time in spite of being the square distance the
>   particle goes. That means that the particle undergoes diffusive motion where it
>   advanced only proportional to the square root of time. Compute your diffusion
>   constant D from the curve, and check that D = ∆."

However, I am struggling with this as I am not very proficient at coding, as well as the fact that I am not sure I totally understand the calculation involved.

Here is the code I am working on, note that the final plot is unfinished as this is the part I am struggling with:

```
#%% Brownian Motion

import math
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import random


P_dis = []

N = 10
# N = the number of iterations (i.e. the number of iterations of the loop below)
for j in range(N):
    T = 10000
    # T = time steps i.e. the number of jumps the particle makes
    x_pos = [0]
    y_pos = [0]
    # initally empty lists that will be appended below
    for i in range(1,T):
        A = random.uniform(0 , 1)
        B = A * 2 * math.pi
        current_x = x_pos[i-1]
        current_y = y_pos[i-1]
        next_x = current_x + math.cos(B)
        # takes previous xpos and applies 
        next_y = current_y + math.sin(B)
        x_pos = x_pos + [next_x]
        # appends the next x list with xpos and stores 
        y_pos = y_pos + [next_y]
    dis = np.sqrt((0 - x_pos[T - 1])**2 + (0 - y_pos[T - 1])**2)
    P_dis.append(dis)
    print(j)



plt.figure()
plt.plot(x_pos , y_pos , "0.65")

plt.plot((x_pos[0] , x_pos[-1]) , (y_pos[0] , y_pos[-1]) , "r" , label = ("Particle displacement =", dis))

plt.plot(x_pos[0] , y_pos[0] , 'ob' , label = "start" )
plt.plot(x_pos[-1] , y_pos[-1] , 'oc' , label = "end")    
plt.legend(loc = "upper left")
plt.xlabel("x position")
plt.ylabel("y position")
plt.title("Brownian Motion of a particle in 2 dimensions")
plt.grid(True)



#MSD
MSD = np.mean(P_dis)
print("Mean Square Distance is", MSD , "over" , N , "iterations")

plt.figure()
plt.plot(, [P_dis] , "r")
```

Any help on the matter would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To plot the MSE with its std with as little changes to your code as possible, you can do the following,

```
import math
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import random


P_dis = []

N = 10
# N = the number of iterations i.e. the number of iterations of the loop 
# below
T = 100
allx = np.array([]).reshape(0,T)
ally = np.array([]).reshape(0,T)
allD = np.array([]).reshape(0,T)
for j in range(N):
    # T = time steps i.e. the number of jumps the particle makes
    x_pos = [0]
    y_pos = [0]
    # initally empty lists that will be appended below
    for i in range(1,T):
        A = random.uniform(0 , 1)
        B = A * 2 * math.pi
        current_x = x_pos[i-1]
        current_y = y_pos[i-1]
        next_x = current_x + math.cos(B)
        # takes previous xpos and applies 
        next_y = current_y + math.sin(B)
        x_pos = x_pos + [next_x]
        # appends the next x list with xpos and stores 
        y_pos = y_pos + [next_y]
    dis = np.sqrt((0 - x_pos[T - 1])**2 + (0 - y_pos[T - 1])**2)
    dis = np.sqrt((0 - np.array(x_pos))**2 + (0 - np.array(y_pos))**2)
    allD = np.vstack([allD,dis])
    allx = np.vstack([allx,np.array(x_pos)])
    ally = np.vstack([ally,np.array(y_pos)])
    P_dis.append(dis)
    print(j)



plt.figure()
plt.plot(np.mean(allx,0) , np.mean(ally,0) , "0.65")
plt.figure()
plt.plot(np.arange(0,T),np.mean(allD,0),'b')
plt.plot(np.arange(0,T),np.mean(allD,0)+np.std(allD,0)/np.sqrt(N),'r')
plt.plot(np.arange(0,T),np.mean(allD,0)-np.std(allD,0)/np.sqrt(N),'r')
```

[image: MSE vs time and error curves]

Comment: hi, thanks for the reply, when I run this code, I get ValueError: all the input array dimensions except for the concatenation axis must match exactly

Comment: N was defined after using it, just changed it. Anyways, that's not the problem you report. try cleaning your environment.

Comment: Thank you so much for this, was about to put my head through my monitor

Comment: sorry, just to clarify, the red curves on the plot are the error, correct?

Comment: Yes, but I just noticed they are just the standard deviation. To get the errors you have to divide by `sqrt(N)`. This is, in the last two lines, you have to change `np.std(allD,0)` for `np.std(allD,0)/np.sqrt(N)`

Comment: after doing that you should see that the error bars increase on time but are much smaller.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/202983/discussion-between-u02cjk16-and-myradio).

Answer (score 2):

Let's define:

```
T = 1000       # Number of time steps
N = 10         # Number of particles
step_size = 1  # Length of one step
```

I precompute most of the data with numpy and add everything up to get the motion of the random walk:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Random direction for the N particles for T time_steps 
rnd_angles = np.random.random((N, T))*2*np.pi
# Initialize the positions for each particle to (0, 0)
pos = np.zeros((N, T, 2))                      

for t in range(1, T):
    # Calculate the position at time t for all N particles 
    # by adding a step in a random direction to the position at time t-1
    pos[:, t, 0] = pos[:, t-1, 0] + np.cos(rnd_angles[:, t]) * step_size
    pos[:, t, 1] = pos[:, t-1, 1] + np.sin(rnd_angles[:, t]) * step_size

# Calculate the distance to the center (0, 0) for all particles and all times
distance = np.linalg.norm(pos, axis=-1)

# Plot the trajectory of one particle
idx_particle = 7  # Choose from range(0, N)
x_pos = pos[idx_particle, : ,0]
y_pos = pos[idx_particle, : ,1]
dis = distance[idx_particle, -1]  # Get the distance at the last time step

plt.figure()
plt.plot(x_pos , y_pos , "0.65")
plt.plot((x_pos[0] , x_pos[-1]) , (y_pos[0] , y_pos[-1]) , "r" , 
          label=("Particle displacement =", dis))
plt.plot(x_pos[0] , y_pos[0] , 'ob' , label = "start" )
plt.plot(x_pos[-1] , y_pos[-1] , 'oc' , label = "end")
plt.legend(loc = "upper left")
plt.xlabel("x position")
plt.ylabel("y position")
plt.title("Brownian Motion of a particle in 2 dimensions")
plt.grid(True)
```

[image: Trajectory of one random partical]

You can get an idea of what is happening and how 'slow' the expansion is moving on by looking at the positions over the time:

```
for i in np.linspace(0, T-1, 10, dtype=int):
    plt.figure()
    plt.scatter(pos[:, i, 0] , pos[:, i, 1])
```

You are interested in the mean squared distance from the start point (0, 0) with respect to the time:

```
squared_distance = (distance ** 2)
msd = squared_distance.mean(axis=0)
std_msd = squared_distance.std(axis=0)
sigma = std_msd / np.sqrt(N)

plt.errorbar(x=np.arange(T), y=msd, yerr=sigma)
```

You can chance *T*, *N* and *step_size* to look at the influence on msd.

Comment: thanks for the reply, I'm currently trying to sift through this and make sense of it. As I said, I'm really not very good at coding so I really only have a basic knowledge of python, meaning very limited in terms of what a few of these lines actually do

Comment: That is to say, how can I combine this with the initial part of my code which actually plots the motion of the particles?

Comment: Sorry, I should have stayed closer to your code, I added your plot now